# Compare Firefox: add-on, extension & plugin

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins

```
Firefox>Tools>Add-on
```

references these three items:

- add-on
- extension
- plugin

What are they and what is the relationship or differences between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that both extensions and plugins are add-ons. Extensions add functionality to Firefox, whereas plugins are more about letting you play additional types of media (like silverlight, flash, quicktime).

Comment: This is confirmed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions